# InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url) - Have tried a lot

Tags: python, url

I understood that the topic already exists, but I cannot figure out what is the issue.

This is the code ( I believe it is straight forward )

```
import requests
import config
import time

dataID = "111111"

# If reportis not generated will return 'None'
def get_data():
    dataChecking = None
    checking_url = 'https://api.example.com/v1.1/reports/{0}'.format(dataID)
    responseCheck = requests.get(checking_url, params=(('fields',
                                 'generated_date'), ), auth=(''
                                 + config.authUsername + '', ''
                                 + config.authPassword + ''))
    report_url = responseCheck.json()['report']['generated_date']
    dataChecking = requests.get(report_url).content
    return dataChecking


def download_report(dataChecking):
    urlDownload = 'https://api.example.com/v1.1/reports/{0}'.format(dataID)
    responseDownload = requests.get(urlDownload, params=(('fields',
                                    'download'), ), auth=(''
                                    + config.authUsername + '', ''
                                    + config.authPassword + ''))
    report_url = responseDownload.json()['report']['download']
    dataDownload = requests.get(report_url).content
    with open('' + config.fileDest + '\exportReport.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(dataDownload)
    pass


# Checking report is generated
generatedData = get_data()

# Wating for report to generated
while generatedData == None:

    # Check again if report is generated
    print("Report is generating, Please wait")
    generatedData = get_data()

    # Wait 0.25 seconds between each check
    time.sleep(0.25)

# Report generated, need to download him
download_report(dataChecking)
```

Error is :

```
  raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '2018-06-15T10:37:50'
```

I have tried to change the URL part, using different tutorials, with no success.

`'2018-06-15T10:37:50'` - This is the date when the report is generated, so what I currently do, is trying to check if the data is empty and keep checking it it filled in (with date, as I demonstrate in the example) and then it will run the download part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error seems to be in these lines in the `get_data` function:

```
report_url = responseCheck.json()['report']['generated_date']
dataChecking = requests.get(report_url).content
```

The data structure implies that what you're storing in the variable `report_url` is actually a date, and then you're trying to retrieve that as a url, which throws the error. Figure out where the actual report url is stored and fetch that instead.